# sending json from php to javascript

Tags: php, javascript, json

I have a php variable which contain json, I use json_encode to transform an array to json.

If I print my var I have:

```
["L","M","M","J","V","S","D"]
```

But if I use my var in js I have:

```
[&quot;L&quot;,&quot;M&quot;,&quot;M&quot;,&quot;J&quot;,&quot;V&quot;,&quot;S&quot;,&quot;D&quot;]
```

and I can't parse because I have an error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &
```

Is there a way to get json in my js ?

Thanks

Edit:

In php

```
$dayArray = array('L','M','M','J','V','S','D');
$dayArray = json_encode($dayArray)
```

In js

```
setDayArray('<?php echo $dayArray ?>');

setDayArray = function(dayArray){
    console.log(dayArray);
}
```

With twig

```
calendar.setDayArray({{ dayArray }});
```

This is maybe due to symfony rendering, the only way I found is to do an ajax call using json header

Comment: why did you use htmlentities/htmlspecialchars?

Comment: Show how you are using the var in JavaScript.

Comment: @BadWolf: That's a very bad idea. Yes, don't use `htmlentities`. No, don't just output it directly.

Comment: I edit my post with my code

Comment: `setDayArray('<?php $dayArray ?>')`. That's your problem right there, you have to `echo` it out.

Comment: No this is just an exemple I'm using twig

Comment: You're using it like this? http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/json_encode.html

Comment: If I use json_encode with twig I have an array to string conversion error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the solution

```
calendar.setDayArray({{ dayArray | raw }});
```

use raw to allow html

Answer (score 4):

To output JSON in PHP, output the result of passing your PHP structure through [`json_encode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

Example from the documentation:

```
<?php
$arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);

echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

Outputs:

```
{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}
```

---

Re your updated question, you've used

```
$dayArray = json_encode($dayArray)
setDayArray('<?php $dayArray ?>'); // Wrong
```

Get rid of the quotes, and include `echo` unless it's magically getting output some other way:

```
$dayArray = json_encode($dayArray)
setDayArray(<?php echo $dayArray ?>);   // Right
```

When you do that, the browser will see something like:

```
setDayArray(["L","M","M","J","V","S","D"]);   // Right
```

rather than

```
setDayArray('["L","M","M","J","V","S","D"]'); // Wrong
```

Comment: I have the same problem setDayArray([&quot;L&quot;,&quot;M&quot;,&quot;M&quot;,&quot;J&quot;,&quot;V&quot;,&quot;S&quot;,&quot;D&quot;]);